# How to stop code from trying to load more posts from DB when all posts are loaded

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

My code loads new data when user reaches bottom of the page successfully but still when all posts from DB are loaded code tries to get more posts which results the page to stuck for several seconds. What i need is mechanism to detect when the last post has been loaded from DB and prevent code from executing.

```
function yHandler(){

var id=$(".output:last").attr("id");

        var split = id.split("output");
    var newid=split[1];
    var awrap = document.getElementById('awrap');
    var contentHeight = awrap.offsetHeight;
    var yOffset = window.pageYOffset; 
    var y = yOffset + window.innerHeight;
    var sesid=$("#sesid").val();
    if(y >= contentHeight){
        // Ajax call to get more dynamic data goes here
    $.ajax({
    url:"load.php",
    type:"POST",
    data:'did=' + did + '&newid=' + newid + '&id=' + id + "&sesid=" + sesid,
    success:function(data){

    $("#newdata").append(data);

});


} ///if end

} /// FUNC END

window.onscroll = yHandler;

load.php //
$osql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM answer WHERE respond IS NOT NULL AND question_id='$did' AND id < '$newid' and pinned = '0' ORDER BY resp_time DESC LIMIT 5");
/// while loop which fetches data is below
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to or need to handle the case that other posts could show up via other means while the user is on this web page, then you can just set a flag when you got no more posts and check that flag and avoid the call to `load.php` if that flag is set.

```
// flag so we know when there are no more posts
var noMorePosts = false;

function yHandler(){
    var id=$(".output:last").attr("id");
    var split = id.split("output");
    var newid=split[1];
    var awrap = document.getElementById('awrap');
    var contentHeight = awrap.offsetHeight;
    var yOffset = window.pageYOffset; 
    var y = yOffset + window.innerHeight;
    var sesid=$("#sesid").val();
    if(!noMorePosts && y >= contentHeight){
        // Ajax call to get more dynamic data goes here
        $.ajax({
            url:"load.php",
            type:"POST",
            data:'did=' + did + '&newid=' + newid + '&id=' + id + "&sesid=" + sesid,
            success:function(data){
                 // pseudo code check to see if data was empty
                 // you fill in the actual test here
                 if (nothing in data) {
                     noMorePosts = true;
                 } else {
                     $("#newdata").append(data);
                 }
            });
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could return from backend also the timestamp of the execution, then in client ask for this timestamp to retrieve or not data again. Just like caching works.

(I'll give you other alternative in a minute)

This could be another way (cache by request data):

```
function yHandler(){
    yHandler.lastRequest = yHandler.lastRequest || null;    
    var id=$(".output:last").attr("id");
    var split = id.split("output");
    var newid=split[1];
    var awrap = document.getElementById('awrap');
    var contentHeight = awrap.offsetHeight;
    var yOffset = window.pageYOffset; 
    var y = yOffset + window.innerHeight;
    var sesid=$("#sesid").val();
    if(y >= contentHeight){
        // Ajax call to get more dynamic data goes here
        var newRequest = 'did=' + did + '&newid=' + newid + '&id=' + id + "&sesid=" + sesid;
        if(newRequest != yHandler.lastRequest){
          $.ajax({
             url:"load.php",
             type:"POST",
             data: yHandler.lastData,
             success:function(data){
                $("#newdata").append(data);
                yHandler.lastData = newRequest;  //Save the last request data
             }
          });
        }
   }
});
```

Basically, the above code saves the last request `data`. If in the next scroll it hasn't changed, then don't perform the ajax call.

Hope this helps. Cheers